# Sony Spresenseのboard_sdcard_enable: ERROR: Failed to mount the SDCARD. 22 の解決方法は？

Tags: spresense

メインボードと拡張ボードを用いて、Spresense Arduino IDEのUsbMsc.ino（サンプルプログラム）でSDカードは認識できました。

しかし、SDカードのファイルの読み書きをするプログラムでは、シリアルモニターで以下のエラーが生じ、読み書きできません。
board_sdcard_enable: ERROR: Failed to mount the SDCARD. 22

対応策を教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
ご返事が遅くなり、大変申し訳ありません。

お問い合わせいただきましたSDカードがマウントできない件ですが、考えられる要因は二つあります。

（１）物理的に接続ができていない
（２）SDカードのフォーマットが認識できない

（１）に関しては、メインボードと拡張ボードの接続の問題になります。
メインボードと拡張ボードが半差しとなりSDカードがマウントできないケースは多々報告されております。
今一度、メインボードを上から押し込んでいただき、コネクタが正しく接続されているかご確認ください。

（２）に関しては、SDカードがFAT32でフォーマットされているかご確認ください。
SPRESENSEは、FAT32以外のファイルシステム、もしくはマルチパーティションのSDカードを認識することはできません。もし、そのようなSDカードをご利用している場合は、恐れ入りますが、SDカードをFAT32で物理フォーマットを行ってください。

以上、２点についてご確認ください。

Comment: フォーマットをFAT32で行ったら、解決できました。ありがとうございます。